# Display problem with SWF Tools in Drupal 6: "You are missing some Flash content...."

Tags: flash, drupal-6, swfobject

I installed SWF Tools 6.x-2.5 in Drupal Drupal 6.20. I followed the installation instruction and also setup SWFObject 2 - JavaScript. The status page does not show any error.

The problem that I have is that when I indicate the content with *[swf file="MyflashTest.swf"]* I always get the message:

> You are missing some Flash content
>   that should appear here! Perhaps your
>   browser cannot display it, or maybe it
>   did not initialize correctly

I using apache webserver in my localghost. I tried to open the page with IE and Firefox but I always get the same message

Any idea what do I need to check/set to make flash content appear?

Thanks,
Carlos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using flowplayer to display your videos? I believe flowplayer handles .flv files only.  See here: http://flowplayer.org/documentation/technical-facts.html